# ^@ symbol appearing after piping output (C++)

Tags: c++, pipe, lcs

So I've implemented the Longest Common Subsequence algorithm for the Introduction to Algorithms book (CLRS) in C++, and it works fine, kinda. When I do something like this:

`./lcs abc bc > OUTPUT`

When I open the `OUTPUT` file in `vim`, I see this:

`2 bc^@`

Which is correct, sans that weird `^@` symbol. I did some Googling and this appears to be some sort of `NULL` character?

I've never run into this problem before.. anyone know how to get rid of it?

Thanks!
-kstruct

*EDIT*
Here's the code that does the printing:

```
cout << lcsLength << " ";
    if (lcsLength > 0) cout << lcsString;

return 0;
```

Where `lcsString` is a `std::string`. Not sure if that helps...

Comment: post the line of code that outputs "2 bc"

Comment: I wonder changing that to `cout << lcsString << endl` would help.

Comment: We would need to see what characters are being added to your string.

Comment: Your string contains a literal ASCII NUL in it (note that `std::string`s are allowed to contained embedded NULs).  If you run `for(int i = 0; i < lcsString.size(); i++) cout << (int)lcsString[i] << ' ';` you'll see something like `50 32 98 99 0`.

Comment: Hm, I seem to have been able to fix it by doing `cout << lcsLength.c_str()` instead.

In terms of the last character being `NUL`, is it possible? It doesn't seem to be for me, the recursive print LCS algorithm just prints out the `i`th index of one of the input strings once it meets some certain conditions...

Comment: If I recall correctly, c_str() returns a `NULL` terminated string, which is probably removing, or replacing the `NUL` in the `string` which `cout` handles, not printing the `NUL` character you are seeing.

Comment: Yeah, it's a temporary workaround the problem, but I'd still like to solve the problem. Need to dig through my code to see what could cause my string to accumulate a `NUL` in it...

Comment: `c_str()` is returning the byte sequence `'2' ' ' 'b' 'c' NUL NUL` and then the `operator<<` stops printing when it reaches the first of those NULs.  The `operator<<` for C strings behaves differently than the `operator<<` for `std::string` in this regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've shown the code that outputs lcsString, but unlike a C style string, a `std::string` type can contain null characters since the length is maintained separately from the string data itself.

Try adding the following to dump the contents of the string:

```
cout << "length of lcsString: " << lcsString.length() << endl;
cout << '"' << lcsString << '"' << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < lcsString.length(); ++i) {
    cout << hex <<  int(lcsString[i]) << " ";
}
cout << endl;
```

I'll bet you will see:

```
length of lcsString: 3
"bc "
62 63 0
```

Then you'll need to find out what you're doing to create (or modify) `lcsString` such that it contains a null character at the end.

Comment: Yep, I got a 0 at the end.. time to dig!

Answer (score 4):

That's `NUL` (which is a *character* value, and is defined to be all-bits-zero), not `NULL` (which is a *pointer*, almost always also all-bits-zero, but not required to be).

We're gonna need to see your code to know for sure, but the most likely cause of this is that you printed one more byte of a C-string (which always has `NUL` as its very last byte) than you should have.

Comment: Hm, but I'm printing it with a `std::string`.. I've attached a small code snippet above, let me know what else you may need.